# Prevent variable expansion in Gitlab yml file

Tags: gitlab, yaml

I am trying to define a variable which value will be filled by users when running a manual pipeline. However, in the value I have a dollar sign which truncates the rest of the value due to variable expansion.
I know that there is a checkbox under Settings->CI/CD->Variables which prevents this but that's only if the variable is defined in the GUI. In such a case however this value is not present when I run a manual pipeline. Even if I type it manually - this overwrites the expansion setting. So, is there a way to prevent this expansion in the yml file?

```
variables:
  PASSWORD:
    value: "enter password here"
    description: "admin password"
```